# Single quote replaced to á

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, high-sierra, text-input

When I type single quote with symbol ***a** and ***'*** replaced to symbol **á***. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/304714/edit) your question to clarify whether this happens in all apps, or only some apps? Also, it's good to share what you've already tried to solve this problem, otherwise you risk getting a lot of irrelevant suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to system preferences > keyboard > input sources
2. Remove the item called us international pc, leaving only us or abc on the list